# How to parse the first part of a Text in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Given a database like this

```
birthday(daniel,2018-11-22).
birthday(paul,2000-01-30).
```

I need to find all persons that have a birthday in the year 2018. I have no idea how to do that. I'm thinking about something like regular expressions or string methods from other programming languages. So it would be something like startswith(2018-11-22,2018) => true.

Comment: Use DCGs: https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg by Markus Triska, http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/dcg by Anne Ogborn, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar (has more references)

Comment: Although in this precise case, you could also transform the atom into a list of characters  (atoms of length 1) and check whether the first 4 list entries are '2','0','1','8'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to parse text as your dates are terms of the canonical form `-(-(Year, Month), Day)` so you can just issue `birthday(Person, 2018-_-_)` to get upon backtracking all the persons with birthday in 2018.

To collect all the persons in a list, you may use [findall/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) like this:

```
findall(Person, birthday(Person, 2018-_-_),  Persons).
```